# Does ROS have convenience function calls to convert from world XYZ to camera XY using the camera_info message?

Tags: ros, transforms, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The information is available in the camera_info message, but using standard functionality to convert would be much less error prone, and much less sloppy. Does such functionality exist?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9694/does-ros-have-convenience-function-calls-to-convert-from-world-xyz-to-camera-xy-using-the-camera_info-message?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [image_geometry](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_geometry) package contains helpers to do this.

There is a [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_geometry/Tutorials/ProjectTfFrameToImage) for how to project the XYZ origin of a reference frame into an image, so it should be an excellent example for what you described.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out the "P" matrix in the camera_info message does this more or less directly. I was able to do the needed transformation this way:

From the camera_info callback

```
m_worldToCamera = Eigen::Matrix<double,3,4,Eigen::RowMajor>( msg->P.data() );
```

And then later

```
Eigen::Vector3d imgPoint;
cameraPoint = m_worldToCamera * Eigen::Vector4d( point.x(), point.y(), point.z(), 1 );

Eigen::Vector2d flatPoint;
flatPoint.x() = cameraPoint.x() / cameraPoint.z();
flatPoint.y() = cameraPoint.y() / cameraPoint.z();
```

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2